# Select from 2 tables with a left join

Tags: sql, ms-access

Here is probably an easy one if your used to SQL, which I'm not.

I have this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable 
LEFT JOIN anotherTable 
    ON myTable.myField=anotherTable.anotherField
```

Actually, this query returns everything from myTable which meets the *join condition* (as far as my comprehension goes). This query works great, but I would like to select another field from another table. What I would like to do is something like this:

```
SELECT myTable.*, myTable2.aSpecificField 
FROM myTable, myTable2 
LEFT JOIN anotherTable 
    ON myTable.myField=anotherTable.anotherField 
WHERE myTable.id = myTable2.id
```

However, this doesn't work, I get an error message about the *LEFT JOIN*. I would like the aSpecificField from myTable2 to be added to the rows where the ID of both tables match.

Can you help me building this query correctly? Thank you.

Comment: You have three tables, mytable, mytable2 and anothertable is this right? Why are you not using the Access query design window if you are not familiar with SQL?

Comment: I have 3 tables, yes. I'm good with VBA but still trying to get used to Access interface.

Comment: The Microsoft Access query design window lets you use wizards or drag-and-drop to create queries. You can then tidy up the sql in design view. Add you tables to the design grid, drag the joining fields from one table to the next, and then select the fields you want.

Comment: I'm with Remou here, non of the provided answers so far will be of any use. Access SQL can be simple to write for basic queries, but once you start introducing LEFT or RIGHT joins, it has to satisfy exact parenthesis, I too must say use the query designer (albeit for basic queries I wouldn't as it add's plenty of un-necessary quotes and parenthesis)

Comment: @Remou I ended up going with the Access query design window and it worked, thank you. I got a new question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158913/concatenate-2-rows-in-a-complex-sql-query), feel free to answer. As for this question, just swap your comment for an answer and I will give you the checkmark. I'm quite new to Access and I should read some book to learn how to use it's *power*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft Access query design window lets you use wizards or drag-and-drop to create queries. You can then tidy up the SQL in design view. Add your tables to the design grid, drag the joining fields from one table to the next, and then select the fields you want.

When you wish to advance your knowledge of Access SQL, you can read ...

These are for Jet (<2007), but ACE (>=2007) is not that different as regards SQL

[Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)
[Jet Database Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc805477.aspx)

Background on design

[Fundamentals of Relational Database Design, Paul Litwin, 2003](http://r937.com/relational.html)

An often recommended MS Access book

[Access cookbook](http://books.google.ie/books/about/Access_cookbook.html?id=qtgInMAAA0oC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: Thank you for all those references. A lot of people seem to complain about MS-Access but I don't think it's that terrible.

Comment: Access is not terrible at all when it is used properly and at the proper level. It is extremely useful. However, as with everything, it is not always used properly, so it gets a bad reputation. Anything that is around long enough will have people who complain. Just look at butter :)

Answer (score 0):

List out your fields rather then using `*`.  Like so:

```
SELECT m.Field1, m.Field2, m2.Field1 FROM
MyTable m LEFT JOIN MyTable2 m2 ON m2.ID=m1.ID
```

Per your comment what relation does table3 have with another table?
Just include it based on that relationship

```
SELECT m.Field1, m.Field2, m2.Field1, m3.Field1 FROM
MyTable m LEFT JOIN MyTable2 m2 ON m2.ID=m1.ID LEFT JOIN MyTable3 m3 ON m3.ID=m2.ID
```

Comment: There are 3 tables in my original post, myTable, myTable2 and anotherTable for the LEFT JOIN. It stops working when I'm adding the 3rd table in the FROM clause.

Comment: Okay I edited my answer, its just another join, change the relationship to fit your needs.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. I will need to get used a little bit more with SQL. I thought I could do something like `SELECT m1.f1, m2.f2 FROM myTable1 m1, myTable2 m2 LEFT JOIN myTable3 m3 ON m1.f1 = m3.f3`. It seems like it's not the same thing than adding another LEFT JOIN.

Comment: JonH You are missing parentheses.

Comment: @Remou - Feel free to edit as required, this is a collaborative site.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to return the rows where the ids match for both tables? And not where they dont match? So not a left or right join but a plain join?

```
Select tab1.*,tab2.* from mytable tab1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 tab2 
    ON tab1.id = tab2.otherid
```

Or if you have 3 tables to join?

```
Select tab1.*,tab2.*,tab3.* from mytable tab1 
  INNER JOIN mytable2 tab2 
    ON tab1.id = tab2.otherid 
  INNER JOIN mytable3 tab3 
    ON tab1.id = tab3.anotherid
```

Replace tabX.* with specific fields if needed?

Comment: Not in MS Access. You need to say what type, INNER, in this case. You are also seriously short on parentheses.

Comment: In MS Access, where you have more than one join, you must group them with parentheses. It is very fussy about it, which is why I suggested to the OP that he or she uses the query design window.