# Concatenate 2 rows in a complex SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access, concatenation

I'm using MS-Access 2003 with the query creator. I select everything from one table (`FaitsSaillants`), then one specific row (`WHERE VARIABLE='TitreMandat'`) from another table (`tb_SOMMAIRE`). I want to select another row from that second table and concatenate it.

### The query

```sql
PARAMETERS
    [CurrAxe] Text ( 255 ), [CurrOTP] Text ( 255 ),
    [CurrClient] Text ( 255 ), [StartDate] DateTime, [EndDate] DateTime;
SELECT 
    tb_SOMMAIRE.Valeur AS Projet, tb_SOMMAIRE.VARIABLE, *
FROM
    (FaitsSaillants
     LEFT JOIN Employes
         ON FaitsSaillants.Utilisateur = Employes.CIP)
    INNER JOIN tb_SOMMAIRE
        ON FaitsSaillants.OTP = tb_SOMMAIRE.OTP
WHERE
    (((FaitsSaillants.OTP)=[CurrOTP]) AND 
     ((FaitsSaillants.Client) Like [CurrClient]) AND
     ((FaitsSaillants.Axe) Like [CurrAxe]) AND
     ((DateValue([DateInsertion]))>=[StartDate] AND
      (DateValue([DateInsertion]))<=[EndDate]) AND
     ((tb_SOMMAIRE.VARIABLE)='TitreMandat'))
ORDER BY
    FaitsSaillants.DateInsertion DESC;
```

This query does add the `tb_SOMMAIRE.Valeur` field where the IDs (`OTP` field) match and where `tb_SOMMAIRE.VARIABLE='TitreMandat'`. It works like a charm. However, I want to add another row to the `tb_SOMMAIRE` results. I would like to get the row where `VARIABLE='TitreMandat'` (that part is actually working) and the row where `VARIABLE='NomInstallation'`. I will get 2 rows and I want those 2 rows to be concatenated and displayed when I ask for `Projet` (`tb_SOMMAIRE.Value as Projet`). Both rows' `OTP` (IDs) are the same as the one selected in `FaitsSaillants`.

Sorry if it's in French.

### Tables' structure

FaitsSaillants

> ```
> Index AutoNumber
> Projet Text
> Axe Text
> Client Text
> OTP Text
> FaitSaillant Memo
> DateInsertion Date
> Utilisateur Text
> ```

tb_SOMMAIRE

> ```
> OTP Text
> VARIABLE Text
> Valeur Text
> ```

### Data example

tb_SOMMAIRE

> ```
> OTP   VARIABLE        Valeur
> UGPSW NomInstallation PosteNemiscau
> UGPSW TitreMandat     oscilloperturbographe
> UGPSW RespIng         CU9656
> GWIHK NomInstallation AnotherInstallation
> GWIHK TitreMandat     Anytitle
> GWIHK Responsable     ImportantPerson
> ```

Comment: Show some example data and example results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
PARAMETERS [CurrAxe] TEXT ( 255 ), [CurrOTP] TEXT ( 255 ), [CurrClient] TEXT (
255 ), [StartDate] DATETIME, [EndDate] DATETIME;

SELECT q.Projet, *
FROM   (faitssaillants f
LEFT JOIN employes e
ON f.utilisateur = e.cip)
INNER JOIN (
SELECT s1.otp,
     [s1].[valeur] & "," & [s2].[valeur] AS Projet
FROM   (
  SELECT otp, valeur
  FROM   tb_sommaire
  WHERE  [variable] = 'TitreMandat') AS s1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT otp, valeur
   FROM   tb_sommaire 
   WHERE  [variable] = 'NomInstallation') AS s2
ON s1.otp = s2.otp) q
ON f.otp = q.otp
WHERE f.otp  = [currotp] 
AND f.client LIKE [currclient] 
AND f.axe LIKE [curraxe] 
AND Datevalue([dateinsertion]) 
    Between [startdate] And [enddate] 
ORDER  BY f.dateinsertion DESC;
```

It is always best to avoid referencing all fields as *. Fields (columns) should be listed by name.

The above depends on creating a derived table that groups rows from tb_sommaire by Otp. You can cut and paste the derived table into a query design screen (sql view) to check that the rows returned are as expected.

Comment: Even if there are only 5 parameters, I got an error saying I need to enter 6. The 6th parameter is q.value???

Comment: Another error message. It's in French, but basically, it says the syntax is incorrect or too complex to be evaluated. It suggests to assign *parts* to *variables*. However, the query seems to render correctly in the design window, it's when it's executed that I get the error message. Thanks for your help by the way, really much appreciated.

Comment: This is a different problem. Is faitssaillants a table or a query? If it is a query that is likely to be the problem and you will need to post the sql. If not, you will need to include more information about you table structures and data in your question.

Comment: What is valeur and why is it text? What kind of data does it contain?

Comment: Nope. It says the data is incompatible with the criteria, and then Access points to the OTP field.

Comment: Please post some sample data from tb_sommaire.

Comment: Well, I haven't created this structure, I just have to work with it, but basically, instead of having 50 columns in tb_SOMMAIRE, there is a column for variables and another for values. OTPs are IDs, so for a ID, I might have 20-30 variables and a value for each one.

Comment: Okay, please post some sample data for NomInstallation and TitreMandat variables including otp, variable and value. (BTW it sounds like a good design.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18862/discussion-between-remou-and-dnll)

Comment: I added some data from tb_SOMMAIRE, I cut off some usefulness rows obviously. You can see the data for two distinct OTPs with the two specific rows I want to concatenate and another random row.

Comment: It just works. And the concatenation is finally in the SQL itself. Wow, thank you very much. Did you use the query design window to do this?

Comment: No. At some stage you must move on, however, you can refer to a query in the query design window, so you could build it up with three queries created in the query design window. This is not the worst way to get an understanding of the SQL involved. Once yu have the three queries, you can start substituting the name of the query with the SQL to create a derived table.

Comment: This is the first time ever I heard about the concept of *derived table*. Thank you again, I should be able to do a lot from that single complex query.