# From multiple Access-SQL rows to one row

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, concatenation

This is a follow up to my previous question [Concatenate 2 rows in a complex SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158913/concatenate-2-rows-in-a-complex-sql-query).

Here is what I got from this question:

```sql
PARAMETERS [CurrAxe] TEXT ( 255 ), [CurrOTP] TEXT ( 255 ), [CurrClient] TEXT (
255 ), [StartDate] DATETIME, [EndDate] DATETIME;

SELECT q.Projet, *
FROM   (faitssaillants f
LEFT JOIN employes e
ON f.utilisateur = e.cip)
INNER JOIN (
SELECT s1.otp,
     [s1].[valeur] & "," & [s2].[valeur] AS Projet
FROM   (
  SELECT otp, valeur
  FROM   tb_sommaire
  WHERE  [variable] = 'TitreMandat') AS s1
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT otp, valeur
   FROM   tb_sommaire 
   WHERE  [variable] = 'NomInstallation') AS s2
ON s1.otp = s2.otp) q
ON f.otp = q.otp
WHERE f.otp  = [currotp] 
AND f.client LIKE [currclient] 
AND f.axe LIKE [curraxe] 
AND Datevalue([dateinsertion]) 
    Between [startdate] And [enddate] 
ORDER  BY f.dateinsertion DESC;
```

What if I would like to add another row (let's name it s3) with [variable] = 'something else' instead of 'TitreMandat' or 'NomInstallation'? Would it be possible to get all the tb_sommaire.variable as fields and tb_sommaire.valeur as values where tb_sommaire.otp = faitssaillants.otp? It would probably fix my future problems too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do your first solution in two queries including a crosstab.  First query named qry1 SQL:

```
SELECT 
  f.index, f.project, f.axe, f.client, f.otp, s.variable, s.valeur, 
  f.FaitSaillant, f.dateInsertion, f.Utilisateur, e.empname
FROM 
  (FaitsSaillants AS f INNER JOIN 
  tb_SOMMAIRE AS s ON 
  f.otp = s.otp) LEFT JOIN 
  employes AS e ON 
  f.Utilisateur = e.cip;
```

You can add your `WHERE` criteria to this query.

2nd query, the crosstab one:

```
TRANSFORM First(qry1.valeur) AS FirstOfvaleur
SELECT qry1.index, qry1.project, qry1.axe, qry1.client, qry1.otp
FROM qry1
GROUP BY qry1.index, qry1.project, qry1.axe, qry1.client, qry1.otp
PIVOT qry1.variable;
```

then you can concatenate the `valeur`s for each `variable`

Comment: I have to read a little bit more about TRANSFORM and PIVOT. I can't test it yet, but thank you.

Comment: I always use the crosstab wizard and then modify it